# Are IVPs $x'=f(x)$, $x(0)=x_0$ uniquely solvable if $f$ is merely differentiable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Only from curiosity I wonder if the IVP
$$
(\ast) \quad \quad x'(t)=f(x(t)), \quad x(0)=x_0
$$
is uniquely solvable for each $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Note that $f'$ may be locally unbounded, hence Picard Lindelöf can't be applied.

I think it is true in case $n=1$: Let $x_k:I \to \mathbb{R}$ $(k=1,2)$ be two different solutions of $(\ast)$ on an interval $I$. W.l.o.g. assume that there is some $t_0 \in I$ with $t_0>0$ such that $x_1(t_0)<x_2(t_0)$.
Go left until $x_2$ and $x_1$ meet the first time, that is there is some $t_1 \in [0,t_0)$ such that
$$
y_0:=x_1(t_1)=x_2(t_1), \quad \forall t \in (t_1,t_0]:~ x_1(t)<x_2(t).
$$
Then $f(y_0)=0$, since otherwise (by the method of separation of variables)
$$
\int_{y_0}^{x_1(t)} \frac{1}{f(s)} ds = t-t_1 = \int_{y_0}^{x_2(t)} \frac{1}{f(s)} ds 
$$
for $t \in [t_1,t_1+\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$, a contradiction.

Since $f$ is differentiable in $y_0$ we have for some $L\ge 0$ and some $\delta> 0$ that
$$
|f(\xi)-f(y_0)|  \le L|\xi-y_0| \quad (|\xi-y_0| < \delta).
$$
We can choose $\tau >0$ such that $|x_k(t)-y_0| < \delta$ $(t \in [t_1,t_1+\tau],k=1,2)$. Now
$$
|x_k(t)-y_0| = \left|\int_{t_1}^t x_k'(s)ds\right| = \left|\int_{t_1}^t (f(x_k(s))-f(y_0)) ~ ds\right| \le L \int_{t_1}^t |x_k(s)-y_0|ds \quad (t \in [t_1,t_1+\tau])
$$
and Gronwall's inequality yields $x_1(t)=y_0=x_2(t)$ $(t \in [t_1,t_1+\tau])$, a contradiction.

This proof seems not to work in case $n>1$. If $x_1(t_0) \not= x_2(t_0)$ again I can go left until $x_2$ and $x_1$ meet the first time in some $y_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$, but I don't think that $f(y_0)=0$ follows. My first idea was to compare $x_1$ an $x_2$
directly. But from differentiability in $y_0$ it does not follow that there is some $L\ge 0$ and some $\delta> 0$ such that
$$
\|f(\xi)-f(\eta)\|  \le L\|\xi-\eta\| \quad (\|\xi-y_0\|, \|\eta-y_0\| < \delta).
$$
Inserting $y_0$ also seems to be useless, since I can't find any use of
$$
\|x_1(t)-x_2(t)\| \le  L \int_{t_1}^t (\|x_1(s)-y_0\|+ \|x_2(s)-y_0\|) ~ds 
\quad (t \in [t_1,t_1+\tau]).
$$

Maybe someone knows a different uniqueness condition that works (or a counterexample). Thanks for any support.

EDIT: Motivated by the comment of Lutz Lehmann here are some examples of functions I have in mind. The function
$$
h_\alpha(\xi) = |\xi|^\alpha \sin\left(\frac{1}{\xi}\right) ~ (\xi \not=0), \quad h_\alpha(0)=0
$$
with $\alpha \in (1,2)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ (with $h_\alpha'(0)=0$), and $h_\alpha'$ is unbounded in each neighborhood of $0$. According to the observation for the case $n=1$ above for example
$$
x'(t)=h_{3/2}(x(t)) + h_{5/4}(x(t)-1), \quad x(0)=x_0
$$
is uniquely solvable for each $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. In case $n=2$ one would like to consider functions like
$$
f(\xi_1,\xi_2)=(h_{3/2}(\xi_1+\xi_2), h_{5/4}(\xi_1\xi_2))
$$
for example.

Comment: You already get uniqueness if $f$ is locally Lipschitz. You allow that $f'$ is not continuous? How do differentiable and singularity go together, do you have some simple examples?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, I allow $f'$ to be not continuous. As $f$ is differentiable it is continuous, hence there are solutions by Peano's Theorem. The question is if they are unique. For example consider $f(\xi)=|\xi|^{3/2}\sin(1/\xi)$ $(\xi \not=0)$, $f(0)=0$. Here $x'=f(x)$, $x(0)=x_0$  is uniquely solvable for each $x_0$.

Comment: I might be off track -- Consider $x(0)=0$, $x(t)= e^{-1/t^2}$, $x'(t)=\tfrac 1t e^{-1/t^2}$ which can be described via $f(0)=0$, $f(x)=x \sqrt{-  \ln x}$. $x(t)=0$ is another solution to the same IVP, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexK $f$ is not differentiable in $0$ and  $x'(t)=(2/t^3)e^{-1/t^2}$